# Reportlab spreadsheet table formula

Tags: python, reportlab, formulas

I am a newie to python and Reportlab. Currently I am trying to create an invoice by using Reportlab spreadsheet tables. I have discovered the formulas: PreviousPagesColSum, CurrentPageColSum and TotalPagesColSum, which I can repeat on the following pages (repeatRowsB = 3). However, now I would like to calculate the VAT over the TotalPagesColSum, for which I  need to get the value of TotalPagesColSum and multiply it with 0.21, but I cannot seem to find an example on how to do that. 
I can work my way around it by adding a VAT column on the invoice and perform the ColSum on that column, but this is not preferable due to the emergence of rounding differences.

Can anybody advice me on this ?
Thank you in advance.
Helga

Comment: I guess I am unfamiliar with the formulas and spreadsheet tables, but you could obviously also accomplish this by doing the calculations before display which is, anyway, arguably a better design because it keeps display and function separate, allowing more flexible testing and less change of display changes affect core application logic.

Comment: Dear Gordon, thank you for your response, I was so focussed on the spreadsheet tables, I guess I forgot to zoom out. I will start to approach it your suggested way.